# MySQL Persistent Running Total

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

Hope you can help me with this problem. I searched enough, but was not able to find any good answers to what I am trying to do. It maybe impossible but worth a shot to see what we can do.

**Synopsis:**
I have table that stores a product identifier (URL), activation date, cancellation date and a state.
Out of this table I derive two views to generate a monthly activation and cancellation report (I wish i could do it in a single view/result but couldn't find a way)
Finally to get a summary output, I left join the two views at the activations view and also perform a running total column (previous total+new activations-cancelations).

(SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e44d5)

[Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X9z8.png)

So far so good.

**Problem:**
However, if I were to modify the SELECT statement with a date range at the end like below, the running total is only calculated for the selected. This result is correct for the query I run.

However the outcome I want is a continuations of the original running total as I want to show the total of active services for the selected time range.

Say for example, at 2017-07-01 the running total is 500, then for the selected range, the running total should start at this value.

The easiest way to achieve this is for me to store the SQL as a view. But as MySQL cannot create views with variables, with the current query setup this is not possible.

As you all can see, my SQL knowledge is not that great. So I'm not sure what to do from here.

Your help is much appreciated.

SQL Details:

```
CREATE TABLE `pbx` (
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `activation_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `deactivation_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `active_status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`url`)
);

INSERT INTO `pbx` (`url`, `activation_date`, `deactivation_date`, `active_status`) VALUES
('6970', '0000-00-00', '2014-12-04', 'I'),
('5738', NULL, '2012-10-29', 'I'),
('7782', '2014-00-00', '2014-12-04', 'I'),
('1693', '2014-00-00', '2014-12-04', 'I'),
('5118', '2017-03-14', NULL, 'A'),
('511', '0000-00-00', '2014-07-02', 'I'),
('7204', '2018-03-21', NULL, 'A'),
('4485', '0000-00-00', '2014-07-02', 'I'),
('814', '2017-11-16', NULL, 'A'),
('614', '2017-12-06', NULL, 'A'),
('627', '0000-00-00', '2014-07-03', 'I'),
('1295', '0000-00-00', '2014-07-07', 'I'),
('4591', '2017-08-11', NULL, 'A'),
('9074', '0000-00-00', '2014-12-04', 'I'),
('1594', '2018-07-26', NULL, 'A'),
('747', NULL, '2017-09-15', 'I'),
('8955', '2017-08-30', NULL, 'A'),
('2535', '2017-06-02', NULL, 'A'),
('5811', '2017-06-27', NULL, 'A'),
('1447', NULL, NULL, 'I'),
('9805', '2017-11-03', NULL, 'A'),
('4683', '2015-12-22', '0000-00-00', 'A'),
('3999', '2011-01-18', '2013-11-27', 'I'),
('5947', NULL, '2015-11-03', 'I'),
('7736', '2017-12-07', NULL, 'A'),
('839', '2014-06-16', '0000-00-00', 'A'),
('986', '2017-08-17', NULL, 'A'),
('2416', '2015-07-15', NULL, 'A'),
('9121', '2017-06-27', NULL, 'A'),
('8355', '2017-03-01', NULL, 'A'),
('4415', '2017-09-29', NULL, 'A'),
('7008', '2016-01-28', NULL, 'A'),
('1795', '2017-06-28', NULL, 'A'),
('7951', '2018-01-23', NULL, 'A'),
('4368', '2014-12-18', '2015-01-30', 'I'),
('7991', '2014-02-26', '0000-00-00', 'I'),
('6848', '2016-11-23', NULL, 'A'),
('266', '2015-09-23', NULL, 'A'),
('787', '2018-05-02', NULL, 'A'),
('3139', '2014-09-30', '2015-07-06', 'I'),
('3332', '2018-05-02', NULL, 'A'),
('7244', '2017-11-24', NULL, 'A'),
('6222', '2016-05-31', NULL, 'A'),
('9380', '2015-08-19', '0000-00-00', 'A'),
('8233', '2016-08-01', '2017-03-31', 'I'),
('3025', '2017-03-31', NULL, 'A'),
('425', '2018-06-29', NULL, 'A'),
('3053', '2018-02-08', '2018-07-19', 'I'),
('3988', '2013-03-08', '2013-06-05', 'I'),
('782', '2017-01-05', NULL, 'A'),
('1945', '2018-04-05', NULL, 'A'),
('7379', '2016-09-12', NULL, 'A'),
('1061', '2011-09-01', '2016-08-03', 'I'),
('3168', NULL, NULL, 'P'),
('2658', '2018-07-05', NULL, 'A'),
('3787', '2015-12-28', NULL, 'A'),
('960', '2017-01-09', '2018-01-18', 'I'),
('3438', '2017-09-18', NULL, 'A'),
('4310', NULL, NULL, 'P'),
('1236', '2017-08-15', NULL, 'A'),
('3250', '2015-12-01', NULL, 'A'),
('2544', '2018-04-26', NULL, 'A'),
('2969', '2016-12-06', NULL, 'A'),
('7214', '2017-09-26', NULL, 'A'),
('7161', '2015-01-21', '2015-01-21', 'I'),
('4165', '2012-06-18', NULL, 'A'),
('9339', '2014-03-21', '0000-00-00', 'A'),
('4204', '2017-04-20', NULL, 'A'),
('3000', '2014-04-18', NULL, 'A'),
('2388', '2015-07-01', '2017-08-16', 'I'),
('2940', '2016-02-12', NULL, 'A'),
('7536', '2017-12-20', NULL, 'A'),
('8860', '2018-02-21', NULL, 'A'),
('1694', '2018-03-07', NULL, 'A'),
('1890', '2018-02-28', NULL, 'A'),
('4367', '2015-06-03', '0000-00-00', 'A'),
('6167', '2011-09-21', '0000-00-00', 'A'),
('7732', '2015-05-29', '0000-00-00', 'A'),
('158', '2016-09-01', NULL, 'A'),
('7595', '2011-09-05', NULL, 'A'),
('7501', '2016-11-03', '2018-03-12', 'I'),
('4720', '2017-12-07', NULL, 'A'),
('1096', '2014-03-20', '0000-00-00', 'A'),
('1321', '2017-12-06', NULL, 'A'),
('3316', '2016-04-18', NULL, 'A'),
('2617', '2018-05-10', NULL, 'A'),
('3136', '2013-06-14', NULL, 'A'),
('7831', '2013-06-20', NULL, 'A'),
('9746', '2018-03-09', NULL, 'A'),
('5236', '2016-06-06', NULL, 'A'),
('6942', '2016-03-08', NULL, 'A'),
('9005', '2012-12-21', '2016-02-02', 'I'),
('4195', '2012-11-15', '2012-11-15', 'I'),
('3963', '2015-11-23', '0000-00-00', 'A'),
('7229', '2015-08-05', '0000-00-00', 'A'),
('4255', '2011-03-01', '0000-00-00', 'A'),
('9590', '2017-11-29', NULL, 'A'),
('5183', '2018-07-04', NULL, 'A'),
('7147', '2018-01-29', NULL, 'A');

CREATE VIEW `pbx_activations` AS SELECT CONCAT_WS('',YEAR(activation_date),'-',LPAD(MONTH(activation_date), 2, '0'),'-01') as DATE, COUNT(url) as Activations
FROM pbx 
WHERE MONTH(activation_date) > 0 AND activation_date IS NOT NULL AND active_status <> "P" 
GROUP BY YEAR(activation_date), MONTH(activation_date) ;

CREATE VIEW `pbx_cancellations` AS SELECT CONCAT_WS('',YEAR(deactivation_date),'-',LPAD(MONTH(deactivation_date), 2, '0'),'-01') as DATE, COUNT(url) as Cancellations
FROM pbx 
WHERE MONTH(activation_date) > 0 AND activation_date IS NOT NULL AND MONTH(deactivation_date) > 0 AND deactivation_date IS NOT NULL AND active_status <> "P" 
GROUP BY YEAR(deactivation_date), MONTH(deactivation_date) ;

SELECT act.DATE, Activations, IFNULL(Cancellations,0) as Cancellations, (@runtot :=  Activations - IFNULL(Cancellations,0) + @runtot) AS Total
FROM pbx_activations AS act 
LEFT JOIN pbx_cancellations AS can ON act.date = can.date, (SELECT @runtot:=0) c;
```

Comment: Why not use a subquery

Comment: What Strawberry said, but it would be tough for us to even give you that query right now, because your direct question is totally devoid of data and SQL code.  Please include sample data directly in your question, and then show us your current query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated the question with my current SQL that I am using.

Comment: @Strawberry, I will try to do some subquery but not sure how I can wrap this around it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(alpha CHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e'),('f'),('g'),('h'),('i');

SELECT alpha, @i:=@i+1 rank FROM my_table,(SELECT @i:=0) vars ORDER BY alpha;
+-------+------+
| alpha | rank |
+-------+------+
| a     |    1 |
| b     |    2 |
| c     |    3 |
| d     |    4 |
| e     |    5 |
| f     |    6 |
| g     |    7 |
| h     |    8 |
| i     |    9 |
+-------+------+

SELECT alpha FROM (SELECT alpha, @i:=@i+1 rank FROM my_table,(SELECT @i:=0) vars ORDER BY alpha) n WHERE rank BETWEEN 4 AND 7;
+-------+
| alpha |
+-------+
| d     |
| e     |
| f     |
| g     |
+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Strawberry's guidance on sub-query I was able to figure out how to get the result set from the final query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT act.DATE, Activations, IFNULL(Cancellations,0) as Cancellations, (@runtot :=  Activations - IFNULL(Cancellations,0) + @runtot) AS Total
    FROM pbx_activations AS act 
    LEFT JOIN pbx_cancellations AS can ON act.date = can.date, (SELECT @runtot:=0) c
) AS tmpTBL
WHERE tmpTBL.date between '2017-07-01' AND DATE(NOW());
```

This now gives me the desired output without doing complex work.

Before:
[Before Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dw2V.png)

After:
[After Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaEns.png)

Thank you all for taking your time help a stranger.

Comment: Your query has no ORDER BY clause. This is essential to guaranteeing the order of the variable assignment, and hence the order of the results.